# Update table with IF statement from another table in Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

How can I do such query in PostgreSQL?

```
update table1 set column9 = 
sum(
(if sum(a=table2.a + a=table2.b + a=table2.c)>0 then 1 else 0),
(if sum(b=table2.a + b=table2.b + b=table2.c)>0 then 1 else 0),
(if sum(c=table2.a + c=table2.b + c=table2.c)>0 then 1 else 0)
    )
```

Comment: I for one, have no idea what `a=table2.a + a=table2.b + a=table2.c`  is supposed to represent. Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking text tables. ([edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments)

Answer (score 0):

I *think* what you are looking for is the `CASE WHEN () THEN () ELSE ()` statement.

```
   CASE
       WHEN SUM(...) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0
   END
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html

https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-case/

Comment: `sum(...) filter (where ...)`  or probably `count(*) filter (where ...)` is probably more readable.